# Immigration check in Chennai or Mumbai

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, airlines

My itinerary involves three airlines and three sectors:

- Chennai (MAA) to Mumbai (BOM) - Air India
- Mumbai (BOM) to London (LHR) - British Airways
- London (LHR) to Raleigh (RDU) - American Airlines

Is it necessary to do immigration checks both in Chennai and in Mumbai?

Comment: Chennai and Mumbai are both in India. Unless India in general applies border checks to passengers on _domestic_ flights, I don't see any reason why you would pass through one in Chennai.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Some domestic AirIndia flights to DEL arrive in international terminal - and you have to pass through the immigration area (although they just look at your boarding pass and let you through - I think the airline also gives you some card which you surrender to immigration). So it is possible that for passengers flying out internationally they sent them directly to the departure gates - which meant the immigration had to be passed at 1st departure.

Answer (score 1):

Chennai to Mumbai will be a domestic flight. You will have to do immigration at Mumbai airport. Depending on the partnership you may even have to collect your baggage at Mumbai airport and then carry to the British airways counter for further check in.